# Scala match pattern for list

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, match

```
val res1 = -1
val res2: List[Int] = List.empty
val res3 = -1
```

After some operations, **res2** can have multiple elements, but all values must be **-1**

How I can made a pattern matching using this list ?

before this, when `res2` was an `Int`, I used this pattern:

```
(r1, r2, r3) match {
  case (-1, -1, -1) => Success()
  case _ => throw new Exception("Invalid results")
}
```

now I need something like

```
(r1, r2, r3) match {
  case (-1, List(-1, -1, ...), -1) => Success()
  case _ => throw new Exception("Invalid results")
}
```

I know I can use `List.forall` or `List.exists`, but this is outside matching pattern.

Update: I found a solution which works fine

```
val r2res = r2.forall(x => x == -1)

 (r1, r2res, r3) match {
   case (-1, true, -1) => Success()
   case _ => throw new Exception("Invalid results")
 }
```

Feel free to post a reply if exist a method to match directly the result of res2. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [pattern guards](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html#pattern-guards) in pattern matching:

```
(r1, r2, r3) match {
  case (-1, l:List[Int], -1) if l.forall(_ == -1) => Success()
  case _ => throw new Exception("Invalid results")
}
```

Comment: that's what I searched for. Thanks

Comment: @AlleXyS was glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Try combining pattern binder with a guard

```
(res1, res2, res3) match {
  case (-1, (l @ h :: _), -1) if l.forall(_ == -1) => // ok
  case _ => // nok
}
```

Note I used `(l @ h :: _)` pattern assuming empty list should not qualify because

```
assert(List.empty[Int].forall(_ == -1))   // ok
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I checked Guru Stron as solution because I need that all items to be -1